# I press a phone number in History and it is dialed immediately without a confirmation question. How can I prevent this?

Tags: lumia-520

I have a WP8.1 mobile phone (see the picture). It happens many times that, after receiving a call, I have to phone back and by mistake instead of touching the right number I press the one above or beneath and suddenly, without a confirmation question, the number is dialed immediately. Even if I end the call in 1-2 seconds it happened that I was phoned back by people I called by mistake. How can I prevent this unpleasant thing. I know that a confirmation message appears if I press that circle with a man inside on the right of the number but the problem is that I can hit the number instead. I would like to also get a confirmation message even if I press the number. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no option in Windows Phone to enable such a confirmation dialog. Been there as well :-/

Comment: Are there in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-phone third party applications that display the history of calls? If they exist I would like to try them. Maybe they work better.